# Editing ArcGIS Online Web Applications

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-web-appbuilder

I have a web map, created in the Map View Classic which I am sharing as a Web Application on ArcGIS Online.

I created this application using the "Create app" and "Web AppBuilder" in the browser. I have added a number of basic widgets (default) from the options in the application builder.

I have also created a second web map using the new map builder on AGOL. This new map uses clustering and custom Arcade scripts to present data in the web map in a way that makes sense. Using the "Instant Apps" option in the Create app options, I have created a "Minimalist" Web App from the templates provided.

There are some widgets / tools in the Web AppBuilder, I would like to have in the "Minimalist" Web app. As an example, the "Add data" widget is not present in the "Instant App".

I can view the source JSON of both applications using the ArcGIS Assistant.

Is there a way to edit the source JSON of the Instant App to add functionality to the application?

If not, is there any other option / workflow to add functionality between the various application templates for use on ArcGIS Online?

Comment: I can understand this situation. None of the ArcGIS Online apps will give you all the functionality you are looking forward to unless you go ahead with developing and customizing the apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web AppBuilder and its widgets are built using the ArcGIS JavaScript API version 3.x. Instant apps and the new Map Viewer use version 4.x. So no, you cannot translate the widgets between the two.

Consider using Experience Builder instead. It's built on the jsapi v4.x so you can use the new Map Viewer. I believe there is now an Edit widget for Experience Builder but not all the widgets from Web Appbuilder have been ported over to Exp Builder, yet.

If you need deeper customization you can use Experience Builder Developer Edition and build custom widgets or themes yourself to emulate what you've done in Instant Apps. I would avoid attempting to add or edit widgets through AGO assistant, it's a pretty easy way to corrupt the app (speaking from experience).

Comment: Thank you. Out of interest do you know of some basic documentation I could look at to review the workflow of creating custom web applications for ArcGIS Online (if it is at all possible)?

Comment: Here is the documentation on setting up Exp Builder, look for the section 'Create Client ID using ArcGIS Online or ArcGIS Enterprise'. https://developers.arcgis.com/experience-builder/guide/install-guide/

With any customized apps, you'll have to put it on a web server like IIS. It should have it's own URL. If you need to access it from AGO as well, you can add it as an item and point it to the app you've deployed in your web server.